# Help me identify these military ICs

Tags: identification

These are from an old military PCBs. pl. help me identify these.

[image]
[image: 14Pin metal soic]
[image: Russian military ics]

14pin soic
[image: 14pin][image: pl name these.]

Comment: From what kind of PCB you found this? It's a russian device, right?

Comment: Hm... 90 degree tracing

Answer (score 5):

These are military grade radiation proof 54 series TTL chips.

- Top and middle LA8A are quad 2-input NAND gates with open collector (5400)
- Bottom LB1A is quad 2-input NAND gates (5401)

Pinout is unknown. I think you can figure it out yourself.

PCBs should not be old as datecodes of the chips are 2011.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try to substitute these in the schematic and verify the functionality is meaningful.

Comment: What manufacturer is the logo?

Comment: The logo from web says Electronika ussr. But i can't find the manufacturer.

Comment: http://www.vzpp-s.ru/about.htm

Comment: The part numbers are as follows 1505ЛА2АЭВ 1505ТВ1 1505ТМ2АЭВ, the 2 and 3 are the same as 4 and 5 respectively - from the catalog, but no specsheets are available.